# Any way to parse with BeautifulSoup while threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup, python-multiprocessing

How can I multithread links I am parsing?

Basically I'm finding links and then parse these links one by one.

It's doing this:

```
for link in links:
    scrape_for_info(link)
```

links contains:

```
https://www.xtip.co.uk/en/?r=bets/xtra&group=476641&game=312053910
https://www.xtip.co.uk/en/?r=bets/xtra&group=476381&game=312057618
...
https://www.xtip.co.uk/en/bets/xtra.html?group=477374&game=312057263
```

scrape_for_info(url) is looking like this:

```
def scrape_for_info(url):

    scrape = CP_GetOdds(url)

    for x in range(scrape.GameRange()):
     sql_str = "INSERT INTO Scraped_Odds ('"
     sql_str += str(scrape.Time()) + "', '"
     sql_str += str(scrape.Text(x)) + "', '"
     sql_str += str(scrape.HomeTeam()) + "', '"
     sql_str += str(scrape.Odds1(x)) + "', '"
     sql_str += str(scrape.Odds2(x)) + "', '"
     sql_str += str(scrape.AwayTeam()) + "')"

     cursor.execute(sql_str)
    conn.commit()
```

I saw threading is being used while crawling websites, but it's mainly used for crawling and not parsing.

I hope someone can teach me how I parse faster than what it currently does. As when I look at live odds I have to update as fast as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers!

The following did the trick:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool(10) as p:
    p.map(scrape_for_info, links))
```

Comment: This parallelise each batch of links, but if I understood your answer you keep producing those links by scraping pages. If you expect to scrape just one big page, this approach is surely the best one, but it you expect to crawl a number of webpages you would accumulate a big overhead creating a destroying processes all the time. My answer avoids said scenario.

Answer (score 1):

With [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process) you could consider using a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Queue).

Typically you would create a two jobs, one that creates urls and one that consumes them. Let's call them `creator` and `consumer`. I will assume that any semaphore is in place here called `closing_condition` (for example using a [Value](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Value)) and the methods you use to parse urls and save them are called `create_url_method` and `store_url` respectively.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Value, Process
import queue


def creator(urls, closing_condition):
    """Parse page and put urls in given Queue."""
    while (not closing_condition):
        created_urls = create_url_method()
        [urls.put(url) for url in created_urls]


def consumer(urls, closing_condition):
    """Consume urls in given Queue."""
    while (not closing_condition):
        try:
            store_url(urls.get(timeout=1))
        except queue.Empty:
            pass


urls = Queue()
semaphore = Value('d', 0)

creators_number = 2
consumers_number = 2

creators = [
    Process(target=creator, args=(urls, semaphore))
    for i in range(creators_number)
]

consumers = [
    Process(target=consumer, args=(urls, semaphore))
    for i in range(consumers_number)
]

[p.start() for p in creators + consumer]
[p.join() for p in creators + consumer]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a great example available in ***Automate the Boring Stuff with Python***.

https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter15/

Basically you need to use `threading` module to create a different thread for each of your urls and then wait for all of them to finish.

```
import threading

def scrape_for_info(url):
    scrape = CP_GetOdds(url)

    for x in range(scrape.GameRange()):
        sql_str = "INSERT INTO Scraped_Odds ('"
        sql_str += str(scrape.Time()) + "', '"
        sql_str += str(scrape.Text(x)) + "', '"
        sql_str += str(scrape.HomeTeam()) + "', '"
        sql_str += str(scrape.Odds1(x)) + "', '"
        sql_str += str(scrape.Odds2(x)) + "', '"
        sql_str += str(scrape.AwayTeam()) + "')"

     cursor.execute(sql_str)
     conn.commit()

# Create and start the Thread objects.
threads = []
for link in links:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=scrape_for_info, args=(link))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

# Wait for all threads to end.
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
print('Done.')
```